# How to capture a server side web api call in fiddler?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, asp.net-web-api, fiddler

I have got the a service with the following topology.

A (Web application) ---calls---> B (Local Web Api) ---calls---> C (Remote Web Api)

I am trying to capture the traffic from B to C in Fiddler, but nothing is logged.

B is a web site hosted locally on my dev box in IIS. It's running on an app pool with a credential other than mine as it has a different set of permissions. Traffic going out from B is not getting logged, even after I have done the following redirect:

```
<system.net>
<defaultProxy
                enabled = "true"
                useDefaultCredentials = "true">
<proxy autoDetect="false" bypassonlocal="false" proxyaddress="http://127.0.0.1:8888" usesystemdefault="false" />
</defaultProxy>
```

What can I do to capture traffic leaving B?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that the .NET Framework is hardcoded to bypass the proxy for `localhost` addresses. Change the target address to `localhost.fiddler` and the traffic will be captured.

Comment: How to change proxy for localhost to localhost.fiddler?

Comment: You don't need to change the proxyaddress, you need to change the URL of the request that your application makes, replacing "localhost" with "localhost.fiddler".